# select closest non null value to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a VERY LARGE table with a timestamp and a value V. Some of the Vs might be null:

```
timestamp,V
sometime_1,value1
sometime_2,value2
sometime_3,NULL
sometime_4,value4
```

I want a query to select the value V of a given timestamp T, but if it is NULL, get me the value at the time closest to T on either side of T. For example, if I have

```
2010-09-01 00:00:01,v1
2010-09-01 00:00:02,v2
2010-09-01 00:00:03,NULL
2010-09-01 00:00:04,NULL
2010-09-01 00:00:05,v3
```

I want the query for timestamp "3" to return "v2" because 2 is closer to 3 than 5, but would want the query for timestamp "4" to return v3 because 5 is closer.

*Time* is not guaranteed to be contiguous either, e.g., we may have:

```
2010-09-01 00:00:01,v1
2010-09-01 00:00:04,v2
2010-09-01 00:00:30,NULL
2010-09-01 00:00:42,NULL
2010-09-01 00:00:50,v3
```

In which case v3 is closest to both 30 and 42.

Currently, I'm doing this by connecting Python to SQL and starting a for loop in both directions from the timestamp in question, and returning the closest value that does not return NULL. But if I can do this in SQL, it would be much cleaner. I cannot write a stored procedure; this has to be a single query.

I am doing this because I need the closest (temporally) valid value for a given timestamp, but sometimes the value is NULL for the timestamp.

Comment: what dbms are you using ?

Comment: edited in main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @par solution but with time:

```
SELECT v
FROM (
 (SELECT v, TIMEDIFF(T, `timestamp`) AS tdiff
   FROM table_name
   WHERE `timestamp` <= T AND v IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
   LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
 (SELECT v, TIMEDIFF(`timestamp`, T) AS tdiff
   FROM table_name
   WHERE `timestamp` > T AND v IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
   LIMIT 1)
) u
ORDER BY tdiff
LIMIT 1
```

Here `T` is given timestamp to search for value `V`.

To speed up you must have index on `timestamp` column.

Comment: I am receiving the error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: Just incase I fat fingered something, the exact query I am trying with V and T filled in is here: http://pastebin.com/9Ga2A6Em

Comment: Corrected: each `SELECT` subquery must be enclosed in parentheses

Comment: Works like a charm now as a drop in, thanks! It's not fast, but as you said that is probably due to my indexing. A more complicated solution might be to select all rows within a month (for example) of T to narrow down the number of rows selected. The timestamp column in the table is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourTable.value != NULL ORDER BY ABS(queriedTime - YourTable.time) ASC LIMIT 1
```

Do not have SQL available to me currently, so the above query might not work (did not test it).

Comment: Question changed; answer will no longer work. Convert datetimes to integers first.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the timestamps are ordered, you could do the following.

This assumes the timestamps are integers, but you can convert from datetimes to integers. I have not tested it, but the idea is there:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE value != NULL && time <= queriedTime LIMIT 1)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE value != NULL && time > queriedTime LIMIT 1)
) ORDER BY ABS(time - queriedTime) ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VIEW like

```
 SELECT T2.T,T2.V FROM TAB AS T2 WHERE T2.V IS NOT NULL 
 UNION 
 SELECT T0.T,(
         SELECT T1.V FROM TAB AS T1 WHERE T1.V IS NOT NULL 
         ORDER BY ABS(T0.T-T1.T) LIMIT 1
        ) FROM TAB AS T0 WHERE T0.V IS NULL;
```

The clause

```
  ORDER BY ABS(T0.T-T1.T)
```

of course may return multiple entries with exactly the same the distance of timestamps under which circumstances different RDBMS may sort differently and you end up with a different value V. 
It also depends how well subqueries are supported on your system.